# javascript create an object with key obtained from value of a key from another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am creating an object from the array of objects, using the value for one of the keys:

```js
const myArray = [
  {
    uuid: '123',
    name: 'abc'
  },
  {
    uuid: '789',
    name: 'xyz'
  }    
];

const newObj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    newObj[myArray[i].uuid] = myArray[i];
}

console.log('result: ', newObj)
```

how can I do the same using ecma6 practices?

Comment: You can use `forEach` on the array (which would have worked in ES5 too). That’s about it for base JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the functions `reduce`, `Spread syntax`, `Computed property names` and `Arrow functions`.

```js
const myArray = [  {    uuid: '123',    name: 'abc'  },  {    uuid: '789',    name: 'xyz'  }    ];

var newObj = myArray.reduce((a, c) => ({...a, [c.uuid]: c}), {});
console.log('result: ', newObj)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

## Resources

- [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)
- [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [`Spread syntax (...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [`Arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Object.assign()` with `map()` and spread syntax `...`

```js
const myArray = [{uuid: '123',name: 'abc'},{uuid: '789',name: 'xyz'}];

const newObj = Object.assign({}, ...myArray.map(e => ({[e.uuid]: e})))
console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are fancy, but I think the most readable, and simplest answer is the following:

```js
const myArray = [{uuid: '123',name: 'abc'},{uuid: '789',name: 'xyz'}];

const newObj = {}
myArray.forEach(item => newObj[item.uuid] = item)

console.log(newObj)
```

*Yes this was available in version 5, but I think is applicable to the goal of the question.*